# Migrating EJB application from Jboss EAP 6.0 to 6.4 named query

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss-eap-6, jboss-eap-7

I have an EJB application that runs in JBoss EAP 6.0.
We are trying (finally) to port to a more recent version (6.4 or 7.0) but in both cases, I have a problem with NamedQueries.

I have a bean as (many properties removed for brevity):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ArtMove")
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "byStoreAndExternCode", query = "from ArticleMove o where o.properties.status='A' and o.externCode=:extcode and o.store.id=:storeid")})
public class ArticleMove{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private short version = 0;

    @Embedded
    private RowProperties properties;
}
```

Where RowProperties is (many properties removed for brevity)

```
@Embeddable
public class RowProperties implements IRowProperties {
@Column(length = 1, nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RowStatus status;
}
```

Upon deploy I have the following error:

```
HHH000177: Error in named query: byStoreAndExternCode: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: o near line 1, column 43 [from ch.oasi.xlnet.eb.ArticleMove o where o.properties.status='A' and o.externCode=:extcode and o.store.id=:storeid]
```

In JBoss EAP 6.0 everything works.
I searched online but couldn't find a solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That query doesn't look correct. There is no `SELECT` portion of the query.

Comment: Thank you James, but even adding the `select o from [...]` to the named query doesn't help. I still get the exception:  
`HHH000177: Error in named query: byStoreAndExternCode: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: o near line 1, column 52 [select o from ch.oasi.xlnet.eb.ArticleMove o where o.properties.status='A' and o.externCode=:extcode and o.store.id=:storeid]`  

And if I check at the _line 1_ + _column 52_ informations returned is just in front of the `o` of `o.properties.status='A'`

Comment: I just tried removing the `o.properties.status='A'` part of the query and the error is gone, so it really should be the `@embedded`...